# Python 3.6 crashes when clicking exit in Tkinter window Mac OSX

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

When trying to close my `tkinter` window using the red 'x' button (top left) the window doesn't close and python crashes(colour wheel).
(note this is across all of my Tkinter apps, not just the one shown)

Here is an image of my code:

[image: Code image]

Here is the crashed white box, neither "quit" or red "x" works. It doesn't show up in the screenshot but the spinning colour wheel is visible whenever I hover over my window. I have to force quit due to "Python not responding".

[image: Window Image]

Got me thinking when I run python in the shell there's an error message: `TK Tcl`. Maybe unstable.

Comment: Hello, please type out your code in the right format, and avoid linking images to the code

Comment: Make sure you don't have other Python instances running by checking Activity Monitor and try running again. Also, paste the code instead of linking an image.

Comment: I have python 2 and 3 running when i quit 2 i couldnt connect to the kernel in 2 or 3. p.s Thanks for the advice i will be sure to type my code from now on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to try `master.destroy` instead of `frame.quit` for the callback of the **Quit** button, and give us feedback whether it changes anything

Comment: I used master.destroy and its still the same, could it be the error message -  "Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable" - I get when launching Idle in 3.6.4? (Im actually using Jupyter)

Comment: Some issues are identified using Tk 8.5.9 on MacOS. See this link: https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk